# Logitech Gamepad F310 Joystick is not working on ROS 2

Tags: ros2, driver, joystick, logitech

I am trying to do teleportation of a mobile robot using ROS 2 Humble and with Logitech Gamepad F310 joystick. I am using the following command:

```
ros2 launch teleop_twist_joy teleop-launch.py joy_config:='Logitech Gamepad F310'
```

I download some packages but none of them working such as ros2 joystick and ros2 drivers.

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! One way to ensure that the operating system recognizes Joystick is to look at the device file ID under the `/dev` directory in Ubuntu. More information can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joy). If device ID is available then you should confirm that you are using the same device ID in your launch file. Also, please make sure that the device ID is having correct permissions to operate,

Comment: Note that if you are using docker or virtualization, some of the devices may not be available in the container. If that is this case, please update your question to include the configuration.

Comment: Im not using docker neither virtualization.